# Chromatic polynomial of connected graph $ \leq x(x-1)^{n-1}$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Number of proper $x$-coloring, $x \in {1,2,3,4,...}$ of connected graph with $n$ vertices is less than or equal to $x(x-1)^{n-1}$ for $n \geq 1 $.

I think there are two cases that I need to consider

$Case[1]$ If G is connected and has no cycles, then it follows that G is a tree, where chromatic polynomial is just equal to $x(x-1)^{n-1}$

$Case[2]$ If G is connecteded and has some cycles

For second case, I am just not sure how to start proof that chromatic polynomial is less than $x(x-1)^{n-1}$

Also, would it suffice to consider above two cases to prove the claim?

Comment: A connected graph has a spanning tree. The number of proper colorings of a graph is less than or equal to the number of proper colorings of its subgraph.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true (if we treat the chromatic polynomial as a polynomial).  As a counterexample, take:

- the tree $K_{1,2}$ has chromatic polynomial $x(x-1)^2$; and
- the complete graph $K_3$ has chromatic polynomial $x(x-1)(x-2)$;

and if we plot these (using [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x(x-1)%5E2%20and%20x(x-1)(x-2))), we see neither is greater than the other for all real $x$, nor for all (or all non-negative) rational $x$, nor for all integers $x$:

[image]

However, it is true (from the definition of a [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial)) if we restrict to non-negative integers.  (But this means we don't use the polynomial-ness of the chromatic polynomial; we're just counting colorings.)

- Any connected graph $G$ contains spanning tree $T$.  The graph $T$ for $x \in \mathbb {Z}^{\geq 0}$ admits $x(x-1)^{n-1}$ distinct $x$-colorings.
- Any $x$-coloring of $G$ is an $x$-coloring of $T$.

Thus $P(G;x) \leq P(T;x) = x(x-1)^{n-1}$ for $x \in \mathbb {Z}^{\geq 0}$.