# Chromatic polynomial of non-tree graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

If x ≥ 3 and G is not a tree, show that $χ(G, x) < x(x−1)^{n−1}$

I think if G is connected, the result is trivial.

How can I deal with the case that G is not connected?

Comment: By assuming $G$ is connected, I think. The statement is false for the empty graph on $n$ vertices.

Comment: but if g is connected, isn't it going to be less than or equal to? not strictly less than

Comment: If $G$ is connected *and not a tree* the inequality is strict.

Comment: If $G$ is connected and not a tree, then it has a unicyclic spanning subgraph. So you can assume that $G$ is a unicyclic graph.

Comment: To bof, I found that the number of chromatic coloring of graph G is less than or equal to its induced subgraph. If G is connected, then it has spanning tree. Then, how is strict inequality possible?

Comment: If $G$ is a unicyclic connected graph on $n$ vertices and it contains a cycle of length $m,$ then what is its chromatic polynomial?

Comment: @bof: $x(x-1)$ is greater than the zero polynomial at all integer values, but not at all real values.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil But the zero polynomial is not a chromatic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2759583/91818) to the [Chromatic polynomial of connected graph $ \leq x(x-1)^{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758293/chromatic-polynomial-of-connected-graph-leq-xx-1n-1), I explain how it's not true for the polynomials (giving a counterexample).

It's true if we restrict to non-negative integers, but this means we're counting $x$-colorings for $x \geq 0$ (and the polynomial is just a distraction).

In this question, $\chi(G, x) < x(x−1)^{n−1}$ is not true when $G$ is a tree.  After changing $<$ to $\leq$ and restricting to non-negative integers, yes, it's not difficult (a $x$-coloring of $G$ gives an $x$-coloring of a spanning tree).

If we allow $G$ to be a disconnected graph, then it's not true even when $x$ is restricted to positive integers.  An $n$-vertex graph with no edges has the chromatic polynomial $x^n$.